# Would adding tags to an answer make it easier to find?

Tags: feature-request, answers

Some responses to questions are specific to a particular domain, but because the keyword for that domain is not in the original question, it is not always easy to find the answer you seek.

For example, some time ago I wrote an answer on how to configure permissions for SenseNet. This issue comes about from an incorrect SignalR configuration. Neither [signalr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signalr) nor [sensenet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sensenet) were in the original question or tags, and I did not put `SignalR` in my answer. Mistake!

Long afterwards I wanted to quickly look up my answer, so I typed `signalr` into the Search box and got 15,569 results. I added the keyword "SenseNet" (found only in my answer) and got 0 results. OK, words in the answer are not searched by default, so I queried "user:me is:answer" and still got more results than I wanted to review. I then added "body:signalr" and got zero results. Damn! I didn't have the word in my answer, so I modified it "body:SenseNet" and narrowed it down to 9 results. Found it!

It occurred to me that if tags were allowed in answers, that I would have put in the appropriate tags so that I would find this immediately without having to use "advanced" search features.

The problem: **SO does not allow keyword tags in answers**.

Possible solutions:

1. Edit the original post with tags -- not a great solution as this could make searching even worse!
2. Modify SO to allow tags in an answer.
3. Edit the answer to allow custom searching, e.g. add "keyword:signalr" to the response so that you can search the body.

I edited my answer with solution #3 so that this wouldn't happen again.

Perhaps I'm making too big of a deal of this, but perhaps adding tags to answers could be beneficial.

---

**EDIT:** in response to questions in comments:

Turns out this was a PIBKAC error. Thanks for the responses -- I'm going to delete this question, as SO does what I want. Once I added the keywords to my answer, the query came back exactly as I wanted.

Comment: Why not adding the tag to the question? People usually search for questions (that hopefully have answers). Another question - why didn't you simply go to your profile to easily find your answer?

Comment: This gives me one result: `SenseNet signalr user:2391063` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SenseNet+signalr+user%3A2391063+) - But i'm not sure I unerstand the issue, how the first suggestion will make searching even worse (As you said), while the 2nd and 3rd won't? IMO they are just as bad in the term of making search even worse

Comment: If an answer needs to be tagged in a different way than the question it's attached to, then there is something badly wrong with the answer.

Comment: Correct. See my updated answer. This question will be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

This might be useful in rare cases, but I think there are probably a lot more cases where tagging an answer differently from a question is just a sign that either

1. The question is too broad, or
2. Your answer belongs on another question.

If you don't think you should retag a question, then it's a good sign you have an answer that belongs elsewhere. You might consider posting your own question that outlines the specific problem you were having, then post your answer under that.

Comment: I agree. As it turns out the "real" reason I couldn't find what I wanted was due to operator error (me not adding the key words of interest to my answer). However, as I'm tending to use SO as my personal Wiki, your suggestion regarding posting a new question is most apropos.